# how does c compiler represents unsigned integer internally

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{
int num=0,num1;
do
{
num++;
num1=num+1;
}while(num1>num);
printf("\nthe largest +ve value int can have is:%d",num);
printf("\nthe largest -ve value int can have is:%d",num1);
}
```

Output:
the largest +ve value int can have: 2147483647
the largest -ve value int can have: -2147483648

the problem is that even if i take "unsigned int" instead of "int" the result is same.

Comment: Did you use `"%u"` when you used `unsigned int`? If you want to print an unsigned value, you should print an unsigned value.

Comment: It's platform dependent, you shouldn't care, and if you do care C99 has specific types with a set number of bits. You should however use `%u` like Zeta said.

Comment: In memory an unsigned int is indistinguishable from a signed int which is indistinguishable from 4 adjacent characters.  You have to tell the compiler (and printf) which is which.

Comment: Note that overflow of signed integers is undefined behaviour, and therefore, the compiler can assume that `while(num1>num)` always holds (my gcc does with `-O2`, clang with `-O1`; the gist of `main` becomes `.L2: jmp .L2`).

Comment: You have posted code that works as expected and then asked a question about other code that you have not shown. You have not shown what changes you make to the code to “take ‘unsigned int’ instead of ‘int’”. You should not expect a correct diagnosis when you do not provide all the information. Show **exactly** the code that you tried, show what it prints, and show what you expected it to print.

Comment: If you change `int num=0,num1;` to `unsigned int num=0,num1;` and change `%d` to `%u` in two places, then I expect you will get output stating the largest positive value is 4294967295 and the largest “negative” value is 0. (The former number may vary if you try the same source code with a different C implementation.)

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're printing it as an integer (`%d`), not an unsigned integer (`%u`). Also, you don't need a loop to calculate this - you can use `limits.h`: `UINT_MAX` and `INT_MAX / INT_MIN`.

Comment: Remark: There exists no `UINT_MIN`. After all, the minimum of all unsigned integral types is known and the same: `0`.

Comment: @Zeta Whoops, fixed. Been a while...too used to `numeric_limits<unsigned>::min()` being defined.

Comment: This does not explain the statement in the question that “if i take ‘unsigned int’ instead of ‘int‘ the result is same.” If the `int` declaration in the source code is changed to `unsigned int` but the specifier is left as `%d`, the output is likely to be -1 and 0, which is not the same as 2147483647 and -2147483648. While the latter is permitted by the C standard, it does not happen in common C implementations. So it is likely that something else is wrong.